# One-liner Python code for setting string to 0 string if empty

Tags: python, string

What is a one-liner code for setting a string in python to the string, 0 if the string is empty?

```
# line_parts[0] can be empty
# if so, set a to the string, 0
# one-liner solution should be part of the following line of code if possible
a = line_parts[0] ...
```

Comment: Do you mean string is empty(means string of length zero) or **None** ?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

```
a = line_parts[0] or "0"
```

This is one of the nicest Python idioms, making it easy to provide default values.  It's often used like this for default values of functions:

```
def fn(arg1, arg2=None):
    arg2 = arg2 or ["weird default value"]
```

Comment: To clarify, if it wasn't clear from Ned's answer: when it comes to strings, an empty string always evaluates to False, and a non-empty string always evaluates to True -- that's why `or` works perfectly in this situation.

Comment: I don't understand - what the difference then to give a default value in a definition of a function: def fn(arg1, arg2="weird default value"): ?

Comment: You can do that, but have to be careful with mutable defaults, or defaults based on changing data that may not be available at definition time.

Answer (score 13):

```
a = '0' if not line_parts[0] else line_parts[0]
```

Comment: Would be more clear as: a =  line_parts[0] if line_parts[0] else '0'

Answer (score 0):

If you would also like to consider the white spaces as `empty` and get the result stripping of those, the below code will help,

```
a = (line_parts[0] and line_parts[0].strip()) or "0"
```